# How to get @LayoutRes int resource from a View object which is created programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way to distinguish the difference between **@LayoutRes int** and **@IdRes int**.
Below you can see a simple example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] days = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};

        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                            linearLayout.getId()/*ERROR*/,
                            textView.getId(),
                            days);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.setContentView(listView);
   }
}
```

linearLayout.getId() returns the **@IdRes** and as result an error has been occurred on the constructor of ArrayAdapter.

The problem is that the linearLayout.getId() on the constructor ArrayAdapter is highlighted as error on android studio.

Below is the constructor of ArrayAdapter

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @IdRes int textViewResourceId,
        @NonNull T[] objects)
```

The second input needs to be **@LayoutRes int** instead of **@IdRes int** which I get from linearLayout.getId()

Can I get the **@LayoutRes** from this linearLayout?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't understand the usage of ArrayAdapter. The first integer from the constructor of ArrayAdapter is expected to be an int value representing the identifier for a layout resource(something like R.layout.your_layout) which is declared in xml in the res/layout folder. You can't simply pass the id off some arbitrary widget you just constructed.

Comment: Because I don't want to use a R.layout from xml is another way to create a List of views? I found that all the ArrayAdapter constructors need as input a R.layout (@LayoutRes)

Comment: *is another way to create a List of views* - Yes, make your own adapter(meaning extending the BaseAdapter class). ArrayAdapter is for basic scenarios where you need an adapter.

Comment: Thank you @Luksprog for your time, I'll search it more :)